# Jquery: Toggle class on click, but also depending on screensize

Tags: jquery, css, screen

I'm wondering the best way to go about this problem, I want to toggle a css class on an element when clicking on a div, via jquery, which I know how to do without issues, but I also want that toggle class to only take effect under a specific screen size, in this case under 800px. I'm not too familiar with JS so I wouldn't be surprised if there's a very simple solution but I couldn't find one googling. Any help is much appreciated as always :)

Cheers!

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.div').click(function() {
  $('.nav').toggleClass('fixed');
});
```

Css:

```
.fixed{ position:fixed;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to get window width using jquery 
so you get window width using **$(window).width()** function

```
jQuery('.div').click(function() {
  if(jQuery(window).width() < 800 ) {
    $('.nav').toggleClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.